# Execute a python command within vim and getting the output

Tags: python, vim

When Vim is compiled with Python support, you can script Vim with Python using the `:python` command. How would I go about using this to execute the command and insert the result under the cursor? For example, if I were to execute `:python import os; os.listdir('aDirectory')[0]`, I would want the first filename returned to be inserted under the cursor.

**EDIT:** To clarify, I want the same effect as going to the terminal, executing the command, copying the result and executing `"+p`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works fine for me:
write the python code you want to execute in the line you want.

```
import os
print(os.listdir('.'))
```

after that visually select the lines you want to execute in python

```
:'<,'>!python
```

and after that the python code will replaced by the python output.

Comment: But that doesn't use Vim's internal Python support. That uses Vim's shell support.

Comment: This most directly achieves the stated desire of *the same effect as going to the terminal, executing the command, copying the result and executing "+p* expressed by the OP.

Answer (score 5):

```
:,!python -c "import os; print os.listdir('aDirectory')[0]"
```

Comment: It won't let me re-upvote the answer unless it's edited, do you mind adding an extra space or something and saving it so I can upvote?

Comment: Also, how can I do it so that the result is inserted _at_ the cursor rather than the line below (with `:r`) or replacing the line completely (with `:,`)? Basically, I want the same effect as going to the terminal, executing the command, copying the result and executing `"+p`.

Comment: @Chinmay Kanchi: no, you can read and very quickly: i think i edited the post while you were testing the wrong code. The `,!` don't let you to insert the output of a command at cursor position but replace the current line with the new one.

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign it to the current line, you can use the vim module:

```
:python import os; import vim; vim.current.line=os.listdir('.')[0]
```

Comment: This works ok, but you end up with a command like `:python import os; import vim; vim.current.line = vim.current.line[:vim.current.window.cursor[1]]+os.listdir('blah')[0]+vim.current.line[vim.current.window.cursor[1]:]` which is a bit annoying :-S

Comment: You could create a command that takes the directory as parameter and put it in your .vimrc:
`command -nargs=1 FirstFile :python import os; import vim; vim.current.line = vim.current.line[:vim.current.window.cursor[1]]    +os.listdir('<args>')[0]+vim.current.line[vim.current.window.cursor[1]:]`

And you can also map some key combination to this for some particular directory:
`nmap ff :FirstFile .<CR>`

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I solved it by writing a script called pyexec.vim and put it in my plugin directory. The script is reproduced below:

```
python << endpython
import vim
def pycurpos(pythonstatement):
    #split the python statement at ;
    pythonstatement = pythonstatement.split(';')
    stringToInsert = ''
    for aStatement in pythonstatement:
        #try to eval() the statement. This will work if the statement is a valid expression
        try:
            s = str(eval(aStatement))
        except SyntaxError:
            #statement is not a valid expression, so try exec. This will work if the statement is a valid python statement (such as if a==b: or print 'a')
            #if this doesn't work either, fail
            s = None
            exec aStatement


        stringToInsert += s if s is not None else ''

    currentPos = vim.current.window.cursor[1]
    currentLine = vim.current.line
    vim.current.line = currentLine[:currentPos]+stringToInsert+currentLine[currentPos:]

endpython
```

This works as expected for oneliners, but doesn't quite work for multiple statements following a block. So `python pycurpos('a=2;if a==3:b=4;c=6')` will result in `c` *always* being `6`, since the `if` block ends with the first line following it.

But for quick and dirty python execution, which is what I wanted, the script is adequate.