# Test a single function from within vim

Tags: python, python-3.x, vim

I am writing python 3 code from within vim.

There is a function within my file like this:

```
def seconds_to_text(seconds):
    return str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds))
```

Is there a way for me to see what it outputs for certain input values from within vim?

How can I see what `seconds_to_text(30)` would output without leaving vim?

---

My plan would be to use the <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> selection mode, grab the relevant lines, and pass them into python through the command line.

However, this has several issues: doesn't import necessary modules, won't capture a function return value unless it is also printed, and probably some other things I haven't yet spotted.

Comment: `:w |  !python -c "import pyfilename; print pyfilename.seconds_to_text(30)"`

Comment: Downvoted because...?

Comment: I think most questions get downvoted when the OP doesn't show what they have tried to solve the issue.

Comment: @Gribouillis well, some 50k rep user posted an answer saying "it's impossible." In the comments of that, I posted what I already did do, which was very tedious but worked, and then they deleted their answer, and probably downvoted this because salt.

Comment: I'll upvote to counterweight the downvote, because I think it's a good question, although I don't use vim. How can so many people still use vim ?

Comment: @Gribouillis oh I love it xD Something about it is so satisfying, I _feel_ faster and more productive, and it means I never have to leave the command line. Idk, I just feel really comfortable with it :P

Comment: You want a REPL, not a text editor.

Comment: @romainl which is what the top answer suggests integrating with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using Python with the interactive inspection?

`:!python -i %`

After the entire script was run, you are left in interactive inspection mode where you can then test your functions as you wish.

If you have ipython installed you can of course also use ipython. ipython has the advantage that it saves a history of commands and you can use the arrow keys to scroll through them:

`:!ipython -i %`

Comment: Nice! This is a really good answer, I think I'll work on creating a function to do this for me, with all the test cases I want.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open vim
2. set your cursor to visual (`v`) and highlight the lines of code you want to translate. 
   -- in this case:

   ```
   import datetime
   def seconds_to_text(seconds):
       return str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds))

   print(seconds_to_text(30))
   ```

**without `print` nothing will be returned**

3. While the lines are highlighted, execute the following command: `'<,'>!python`

Note that those lines will change to: "0:00:30"; and that `u` undoes your last change(s).

Other options, I would suggest is to look at [pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/), and this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608742/execute-a-python-command-within-vim-and-getting-the-output)